# Difference between project-oriented deliverable and product oriented deliverable

Tags: project-management-style, product-management

Can someone please help me with the difference between `Product-oriented Deliverables`and `Project Oriented-Deliverable` in Software Project Management. I found it all-over but didn't find any suitable answers. Forgive me if my question is naive.

Answer (score 1):

Product-oriented deliverables are components of the product that you want to create, which is the reason for the project.  Project-oriented deliverables are products you need to run the project in a healthy, efficient manner in order to build the ultimate product within a reasonable variance of the budget, time, and specs for which you planned.

Product deliverables remain in perpetuity or for its intended mission. Project deliverables are archived or discarded when the project finishes.

Answer (score 1):

### Intensional Definitions and Examples

I can't find a canonical source with formal definitions, but in practice the distinction is between potentially-shippable deliverables and project artifacts. In other words:

- Product-Oriented Deliverable

  A feature, function, component, or milestone that is intended for direct delivery to the customer as part of the product.
- Project-Oriented Deliverable

  Anything else required by the project itself, but not intended for direct delivery to the customer.

Some things will be clearly one or the other, but some things may not. For example, building a continuous integration server would be a project-oriented deliverable, while designing a foo-embiggening widget for the product's interface would be product-oriented. Meanwhile, a foo-embiggening calibrator could be either. Your mileage will vary.